# How to set generic parameter to Query object of Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have created a generic method which will take `hibernate named query`, a `HashMap` object which contain parameter name values for that named query in the following manner:

The method signature is:

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T> getData(String hibernateQueryName, HashMap<?, ?> 
                                             queryNameValue) throws Exception;
```

Now suppose I have a SQL and its `hibernateQueryName` is empData:

```
SELECT e.emp_nm      AS EMP_NAME
     , e.emp_address AS EMP_ADDR
  FROM employee e
 WHERE e.emp_no > :empNumber
   AND e.name LIKE :empName
```

Here `empNumber` and `empName` are parameter name and they are of type Integer and String respectively.

Now suppose I have one more SQL and its `hibernateQueryName` is studentData:

```
SELECT s.s_nm    AS EMP_NAME
  FROM student s
 WHERE s.dob > :studentDOB
```

Here `studentDOB` is parameter name and its of type `Date`. `studentDOB` is a key that I will get from HashMap.

I want to set these parameter and values to query object like:

```
Query query = getSession().getNamedQuery(hibernateQueryName);
query.setXXX(parameterName, parameterValue);
```

Above code is written in my `getData` method.

There are many query.setXXX methods which are based on `Type` for example `query.setInteger()` but for calling this I need to find the type of `?` which I am passing in `getData` method. Is it possible to use query.setXXX method with unknown type `?`

Comment: I think you may need to rewrite your question for clarification. Are you asking how to use your `getData` parameters inside of a query?

Comment: @JordanD I have edited my question. Please let me know if I was able to clarify my point.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `query.setParameter("name", value)` this does not expect an explicit type.

Comment: Thanks. the `value` is of type `Object` does hibernate takes care of type before using it in named query as in query we may have different types like Date, String, Int...?

Comment: I would recommend trying it and if you run into another specific problem edit your original question. hibernate will take care of types as long as you do not try to cast incompatible types.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of query.set parameter is

`void QueryInstance.setParameter(String, Object);`

You may use `HashMap<String,Object>` as parameter, iterate it in method and assign as per the mentioned method. It will act as generic. I have made generic that way, it may help in your case as well.